How to tangle all source blocks in a subtree?
I would like to tangle both source blocks in foobar for the file specified in the corresponding property, foobar.el. However, I know only of two options neither of which meets the requirement:

C-u org-babel-tangle tangles only source the block at point else issues "Point is not in a source block"

org-babel-tangle tangles all source block in the file. In this case there are 3 of them, which results in overwriting foobar.el and qux.el


For such a simple example I could merge the two source blocks, but this does not work in general (1).
*.org:
* foobar
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle ../el/foobar.el
:END:

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (message "foo")
#+end_src

#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (message "bar")
#+end_src

* qux
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :tangle ../el/qux.el
:END:
   
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
  (message "qux")
#+end_src

Notes:
For example: 1) the file to be tangled has ext sh; 2) source block A specifies the shebang 3) source block B invokes a variable specified in the header (:var ...). Merging A and B would place variable declaration before the shebang, which is unwarranted.

To tangle multiple source blocks inside a subtree to a given file, do

M-x org-set-property-and-value RET header-args: :tangle /path/to/file
M-x org-narrow-to-subtree
M-x org-babel-tangle
M-x widen


The doc string  of org-babel-tangle says: ...When two universal prefix arguments, only tangle blocks for the tangle file of the block at point. So, C-u C-u M-x org-babel-tangle on one of the code blocks in foobar should work in this case: the two code blocks share the tangle file, whereas the one in qux uses a different one.
